# Where is the Mods folder? (Windows 10, version 1.12.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, so, I've searched ***EVERYWHERE*** in my .minecraft folder, but I just can't find the Mods folder. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to create it. Go to %appdata% and then press roaming. There you should find a folder called .minecraft Click it and create a folder called mods.